# Does a hunter's machete increase damage from smite?

Tags: league-of-legends

Smite deals 460+(lvlx30) damage to minions, pets and monsters.  Hunter's Machete causes a champion to do +10% damage to monsters.

Does a Hunter's Machete increase smite damage to monsters by 10%?

Comment: Back in MAH days, son, we used to go out in de' Jungles 'n test tis stuff by ahr-selves. Also, from my Olafy experience, True Damage does not apply any effects at all (besides PAIN!).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, according to [Hunter's Machete](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Hunter%27s_Machete), the passive effect, [Butcher](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Named_item_effect#Butcher), does not affect true damage.  As [Smite](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Smite) is true damage, it is unaffected.